# How to transfer data from input to express, so that later express will transfer data to the database PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I have a ejs file like this

```
<h1>URL Shrinker</h1>
<form method="POST" id="form">
    <input required placeholder="Url" type="url" name="fullUrl" id="fullUrl">
    <button type="submit" id="btn">+</button>
</form>
```

js, Where do we get the input

```
const fullUrl = document.getElementById("fullUrl")
const btn = document.getElementById("btn") 

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let input = fullUrl.value
    console.log(input)
})
```

And server.js (express)
How to transfer input to the server?